# Function argument: ab is not defined

Tags: python

When I run this code, it says that *ab* is not defined. What is the problem?

```
import math
def taylor(ab):
    ab = float(input("What is the parameter precision? :"))
    print(f"Calling taylor: {(ab)}")
    num = 0
    x = 1
    n = 0
    y = 1
    while abs(math.pi - num) > ab:
        num = num + (4 * (x / y))
        x = x * -1
        y += 2
        n = n + 1
    print(f"Calling basel : {(ab)} returns {(num), (n)}")
taylor(ab)
```

Comment: define function like: def taylor():, and call it taylor()

Answer (score 1):

```
import math
def taylor():
    ab = float(input("What is the parameter precision? :"))
    print(f"Calling taylor: {(ab)}")
    num = 0
    x = 1
    n = 0
    y = 1
    while abs(math.pi - num) > ab:
        num = num + (4 * (x / y))
        x = x * -1
        y += 2
        n = n + 1
    print(f"Calling basel : {(ab)} returns {(num), (n)}")
taylor()
```

or:

```
import math
def taylor(ab):

    print(f"Calling taylor: {(ab)}")
    num = 0
    x = 1
    n = 0
    y = 1
    while abs(math.pi - num) > ab:
        num = num + (4 * (x / y))
        x = x * -1
        y += 2
        n = n + 1
    print(f"Calling basel : {(ab)} returns {(num), (n)}")
ab = float(input("What is the parameter precision? :"))
taylor(ab)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the variable *ab* before it has been defined. You can't pass an undefined variable to a function. The `taylor()` does not need to declare any arguments. Removing the argument should fix your problem:

```
import math

def taylor():
    ab = float(input("What is the parameter precision? :"))
    print(f"Calling taylor: {(ab)}")
    num = 0
    x = 1
    n = 0
    y = 1
    while abs(math.pi - num) > ab:
        num = num + (4 * (x / y))
        x = x * -1
        y += 2
        n = n + 1
    print(f"Calling basel : {(ab)} returns {(num), (n)}")

taylor()
```